# How to know the ID of my Facebook's comment box?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook's Comments Social Plugin. How do I know the ID of a comment box so I can use it on open graph to get it's comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides what @Igy wrote, there's no such thing as comment box id for the comments plugin, as it says in the documentation of the [fql comments_info table doc.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comments_info/):

> Note: This table contains a mapping of app_id to XIDs used by legacy
>   fb:comments. It does not contain a map for the current comments
>   plugin, which does not use XIDs.

However, you can use the id of the graph object that is the page of the comments box.
For example the comments can also be found using the [fql comment table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/):

```
SELECT text, xid
FROM comment
WHERE object_id="PAGE_ID"
```

You can find the PAGE_ID by debugging the page with the [Debug tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).
The *"xid"* column that I added to the select is just in order to confirm my first point about the *"xid"*, if you try this method to get the comments (it's easy using the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)) you'll notice that all *"xid"* values are empty strings ("").

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) you don't need the ID, just the URL, as the comments can be retrieved at
`https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=[URL WITH THE COMMENTS PLUGIN]` - I don't think you need an access token for that call

Comment: That solved my problem (where someone had put a non-public-facing comment on something during testing). To remove the comments, we had to go to the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and send a `DELETE` request for the Graph ID of the comment in question, with an access token authorised by the user who posted it. It told us there was an OAuthException, but it did actually remove the comment in question. Thank you!  :)